# Can portions of a site be hosted in another domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

If a client has a Wordpress site on domain A and I want to integrate some pages for them that are coming from a Rails application that I deploy on domain B is there a way to do that so that all pages appear to be coming from domain A? Are IFrames a reasonable way to do this?  I'm trying to add functionality for them without disrupting the existing Wordpress install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes of course. If it's considered reasonable depends on what you are trying to do. I personally try to avoid them.

This one is quite old but still valid: http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil